# Android Cannot resolve method startIntentSenderForResult()

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, android-billing

i try to follow the tutorial from this page http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html

but i have a little problem when i try to use the method startIntentSenderForResult() and i don't understand why, it says that he cannot resolve the method.

I'll paste my code because maybe you can tell me what's going on but before i'll give you a little bit of explanation:

I have 2 buttons in my StoreActivity which i implement with the information from google market with the method queryInventory() and after when i click on these buttons i launch the method buyThings() from my file BillingServiceConnection.

Here are the files:

### StoreActivity

```
public class StoreActivity extends Activity  implements BillingQuery{

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("StoreActivity");
    private BillingServiceConnection billingServiceConnection = new BillingServiceConnection(this);
    private Button storeButton;
    private Button storeButton2;
    ArrayList<StoreItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_store);
        configureBilling();
    }

    private void configureBilling() {
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND");
        serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
        bindService(serviceIntent, billingServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (billingServiceConnection != null) {
            unbindService(billingServiceConnection);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingQuerySuccess(ArrayList<StoreItem> storeItems) {
        items = storeItems;
        storeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_menu_store_button);
        storeButton.setText(storeItems.get(0).getName() + " = " + storeItems.get(0).getPrice());

        storeButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_menu_store_button_2);
        storeButton2.setText(storeItems.get(1).getName() + " = " + storeItems.get(1).getPrice());
    }

    public void storeButton(View view) {
        billingServiceConnection.buyJocker(items.get(0).getProductId());
    }
    public void storeButton2(View view) {
        billingServiceConnection.buyJocker(items.get(1).getProductId());
    }
```

### BillingServiceConnection

```
public class BillingServiceConnection implements ServiceConnection {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("BillingServiceConnection");
    private static final String SKU_PACK_SMALL = "small_piece_pack";
    private static final String SKU_PACK_MEDIUM = "medium_piece_pack";
    private IInAppBillingService billingService = null;
    private BillingQuery queryCallback;

    public BillingServiceConnection(BillingQuery queryCallback) {
        this.queryCallback = queryCallback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
        billingService = IInAppBillingService.Stub.asInterface(iBinder);
        queryInventory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        billingService = null;
    }

    public void buyThings(String productId){
        Bundle buyIntentBundle = null;
        try {
            buyIntentBundle = billingService.getBuyIntent(3, "fr.xxx.xxx", productId, "inapp", "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
        startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),1001, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0),Integer.valueOf(0));
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1001) {
            int responseCode = data.getIntExtra("RESPONSE_CODE", 0);
            String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");
            String dataSignature = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                    String sku = jo.getString("productId");
                    alert("You have bought the " + sku + ". Excellent choice, adventurer!");
                }
                catch (JSONException e) {
                    alert("Failed to parse purchase data.");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void queryInventory() {
        ArrayList<StoreItem> items = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayList<String> skuList = new ArrayList<String>();
        skuList.add(SKU_PACK_SMALL);
        skuList.add(SKU_PACK_MEDIUM);

        Bundle querySkus = new Bundle();
        querySkus.putStringArrayList("ITEM_ID_LIST", skuList);

        try {
            Bundle skuDetails = billingService.getSkuDetails(3, "fr.xxx.xxx", "inapp", querySkus);

            int response = skuDetails.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");
            if (response != 0) {
                logger.warning("Bad server response code");
                return;
            }
            else if (response == 0) {
                ArrayList<String> responseList = skuDetails.getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");

                logger.info("Details list size : " + responseList.size());

                for (String thisResponse : responseList) {
                    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(thisResponse);
                    String sku = object.getString("productId");
                    String price = object.getString("price");
                    if (sku.equals(SKU_PACK_SMALL)){
                        items.add(new StoreItem("10", price, sku));
                    }
                    else if (sku.equals(SKU_PACK_MEDIUM)){
                        items.add(new StoreItem("60", price, sku));
                }
                }
            }

            logger.info("Server response " + skuDetails.toString());
        } catch (RemoteException | JSONException ex) {
            logger.warning(ex.toString());
        }

        queryCallback.onBillingQuerySuccess(items);
    }
```

If someone can help me i will be really grateful.
Thanks.

Comment: which api version u are using?

Comment: How can i know it plz ? 
I use android 1.2.2 and i do minSdkVersion: 16,  targetSdkVersion: 21.
Is it what you need ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

i found the response by myself, the problem was that startIntentSenderForResult has to be in an activity, so i just had to do that :

BillingServiceConnection:

```
 public PendingIntent buyJocker(String productId){
        Bundle buyIntentBundle = null;
        try {
            buyIntentBundle = billingService.getBuyIntent(3, "fr.xxx.xxx", productId, "inapp", "bGoa+V7g/yqDXvKRqq+JTFn4uQZbPiQJo4pf9RzJ");
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable("BUY_INTENT");
        return pendingIntent;
    }
```

StoreActivity:

```
public void storeButton(View view) {
        //storeButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.joker_select);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = billingServiceConnection.buyJocker(items.get(0).getProductId());
        try {
            startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(), 1001, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0));
        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Thanks.